How to connect input of information in wordpress and sending it using php to the VDS?
How to connect input of information in wordpress and sending via php on VPS (the site itself is on hosting)?
With the second one it is still clear (inserted via snippet):
$remote_ip = 'smth';
$remote_port = smth;

// Create a TCP socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);

// Connect to the remote server
if (socket_connect($socket, $remote_ip, $remote_port)) {
// Data to send
$message = "Hello, this is a message from PHP!";

// Send the message
socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message));

// Close the socket
socket_close($socket);
} else {
echo "Unable to connect to the remote server.";
}

But how to connect data entry (I tried via Contact Form 7), I don't know. It should look something like this (that is, you write the information, click send and it is sent using php)


There's no special method for handling forms in WordPress. If you want to create the form with a plugin and use the data in PHP you'll need to check the plugin's documentation to find out how to develop with that plugin. For a manually coded HTML form you will handle the form the same way you would in a basic PHP application, using the $_POST variable.
